# Why is my app with a WebView containing a link to Google Play being rejected by Amazon?

Tags: android, publish, amazon-appstore

I am developing apps which show a WebView displaying my company's website. On the website, there is a link to Google Play Store. Due to this link, Amazon is rejecting all of my apps.

I have heard about Amazon Policies regarding other 'markets' and they state that it does not support direct links from within the app.

Why are my apps being rejected if they don't contain direct links to Google Play Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are rejecting your app as the website displays a Google Play store link. I had the same issue with app rating link in my app and was not able to publish to Amazon until I removed any thing tying it to Google Play.